# hasclass doesn't work with testcafe CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, css, testing, css-selectors, testcafe

I am using testcafe version - 1.6.1

I am trying to apply an assertion to see if an element is clickable or not (expect to not be clickable).

I've found the elements class name and a dynamic sibling class which appears to not be clickable in the browser element.

I've attached two snapshots below of the actual UI element and its DOM:

- [The element in the UI I want to detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwxdQ.png)
- [chrome dev-tools Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0bHH.png)

for some unknown reason, the `hasclass` function keeps failing because the required class cannot be found.

`.expect()buttonEssentialplan30Mb.hasClass('.c-form-plan-box--disabled')).ok()`

Comment: I'm pretty certain that a method called `hasClass` would take a class name parameter, not a class selector. Try omitting the `.` prefix.

Comment: tried added the ```.```, same issue

Comment: And I kinda doubt that `.expect()buttonEssentialplan30Mb` is even valid syntax to begin with. Please provide a proper [mre] of what you are doing.

Answer (score 10):

The correct code for your scenario is

```js
await t.expect(buttonEssentialplan30Mb.hasClass('c-form-plan-box--disabled')).ok()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the code above doesn't work. It works only with the  ```find``` function. I think that it ```hasclass``` apply only for classes which locate on the same node and my case there are `child classes` which not detect with the ```hasclass``` function

Comment: Yes, you're right. The hasClass method is related to a particular node that is detected by the Selector and not for child nodes.